# How to refactor with promise in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Visual Studio Code suggests refactoring the code to reduce complexity. I don't know what Promise is and how to refactor the code below. Can anyone help me?

```
const handleLoadInventory = async () => {
    try {
      const _data = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/inventory/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        },
      })

      if (_data.status === 200) {
        const data = await _data.json()

        if (data.items.length !== 0) {
          if (inventoryData.length)
            for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(data.items.length / 10); i++) {
              pagination.push(i)
            }

          for (let i = 0; i < 10 && i < data.items.length; i++) {
            showData.push(data.items[i])
          }

          setInventoryData(data.items)
        } else {
          setZeroAlert(true)
        }
      } else {
        setServerAlert(true)
        throw new Error()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setServerAlert(true)
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
```

Comment: So read about Promises: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise + search the web for more

Comment: You are already using Promises. Every function you mark as `async` returns a Promise and you can **only** use `await` on Promises. Using `await` on anything other than Promises either does not do what you think it does or does nothing at all. If you are using `async/await` without knowing what Promises are you should stop and learn what Promises are first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactoring is the art of breaking functions down into smaller units. The key idea behind it is to make a function "obvious" by making them small so that mistakes also become obvious. You don't really need to know anything more than how functions work.

The first part I'd extract is the `fetch` because you'll probably be using it more than once. Copy/pasting the fetch code you have is bug-prone. You may forget to set its content-type or you may forget to include the auth token.

Therefore it deserves to be made into its own function, not just a piece of code:

```
// This function returns a promise because fetch returns a promise:
function get (url) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
    },
  })
}
```

Next is handling of status code 200. You are using an `if` block. That means making sure all functions that fetch data have the same structure. Again it is error prone because of copy/paste programming.

Since you are setting a state and throwing an error anyway you can handle it in the `get()` function above:

```
// This function returns a promise because fetch returns a promise:
async function get (url) {
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
    },
  })

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error('Server response invalid')
  }
  return response
}
```

The `setServerAlert()` will be handled by your outer try/catch block since we are throwing an error.

Now your code is considerably simplified:

```
const handleLoadInventory = async () => {
  try {
    const _data = await get('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/inventory/')
    const data = await _data.json()

    if (data.items.length !== 0) {
      if (inventoryData.length)
        for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(data.items.length / 10); i++) {
          pagination.push(i)
        }

      for (let i = 0; i < 10 && i < data.items.length; i++) {
        showData.push(data.items[i])
      }

      setInventoryData(data.items)
    } else {
      setZeroAlert(true)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    setServerAlert(true)
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Personally I'd even move the `_data.json()` part into the `get()` function but I think you get the point.